# Windows BAT how to substitute drive letter?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to work from my thumbdrive, therefore i am setting the java path the java installion inside of my own thumbdrive. However, i am not always on a PC that is always a "G:\", sometimes it may be H or F depending on how many devices are currently connected.

How may i rewrite this bat so that it is more dynamic?

```
set Path=G:\dev\04 jdk\jdk1.6.0_29\bin;%Path%

".\dev\01 ide\eclipse-jee-indigo-SR1-win32\eclipse.exe"

pause
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The drive the file was started from is in `%~d0` (`%0` being the files full start path).
If the drive was `G:\` then after double clicking the file in explorer, or running `C:\>G:\the.bat` then `%~d0 === G:`

So you can;

```
set Path=%~d0\dev\04 jdk\jdk1.6.0_29\bin;%Path%
```